# Sometimes it shows components of panel, sometimes it doesnt even show panel in frame

Tags: java, swing, frame, jtextfield, jcomponent

I'm making a very basic application here, I have coded several times more complex gui applications but for some reason I'm having an error with a panel that is sometimes showing its components and sometimes the panel doesnt even show in the frame.

Panel is composed of two basic components: 1 button and 1 Jtextfield. The buttons shows sometimes, the Jtextfield doesnt even show?

I'm using GridBagLayout. The following is the very simple code:

```
public class Start extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public static HomeList home;
public static String user = "default";
public GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

public Start(){

    super("title");
    this.pack();
    this.setSize(800, 500); // w h
    this.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);

    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
    pane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    this.getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
        button.setActionCommand("login");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(button,c);

        JTextField text = new JTextField(20);
        text.setVisible(true);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(text,c);


}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Start();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    if("login".equalsIgnoreCase(ae.getActionCommand())){
        this.dispose();
        home = new HomeList(user);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Sometimes? See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using `setVisible(true)` before adding components to the jframe

Comment: I dont understand, I've done many where I use visible like here and it works normally? (I just tried it and yes it worked, I just dont understand how this worked in other projects).

Comment: @ChristianFeo: what's not to understand. You're setting it visible before adding components, so it makes sense that components added after the setVisible call will not be visible and that you're experiencing the misbehavior that you're seeing. Whether it works on other projects is irrelevant. 1+

Answer (score 1):

Move `this.setVisible(true);` at the end of the constructor

Components should be made visible after they are built.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try `this.update()` method when adding something in the frame.